# Magento calculate price of cross sell product based on cart total

Tags: magento-1.9, php, event-observer, price

What's the easiest way to display a custom price for a cross sell product? The price is calculated based on a percent of the users' cart subtotal.
I currently have an observer that tracks when the cart is updated and I do the calculations there but how to get the price in the phtml file?

Please note that the product is NOT in the cart, so I can't use quoteItem to modify the price. This product is displayed in the cross sell area and the price needs to change based on the cart subtotal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found a working solution by calculating the price separately for each state (added or not to cart). So, for crosssell product I simulated the price on frontend and once in cart, I changed the price through an observer.
It works just fine for what I wanted to achieve.